# Creating an initial install page Android

Tags: android

I am attempting to include an on-install tutorial for my Android application. This tutorial would include the following:

A certain button will be highlighted (as if a spotlight was shone on it, with everything else dark / shadowy). The user will only be able to hit that button; no other button will be active. Once the button is click, another activity / fragment appears and a similar feature occurs with a single button highlighted.

How exactly would I go about implementing this?

Comment: What you're describing is just a navigation flow between different Fragments/Activities, so what exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Take your pick at a library. Good luck! https://android-arsenal.com/tag/198

Comment: I was confused as how to go about creating / implementing this navigation flow (fairly new to Android) but I found a library that may help! Thank you